# Importing IFC file in CityEngine?

Tags: cityengine, bim

I am trying to integrate BIM and GIS. I have IFC file, I try to import the file into CityEngine, but I failed to do so, because its say that my ifc. Files does not have a projection. I try to select projection in the list, but when I click OK button, the dialog still remains the same. Before this, I had opened the if file in ArcMap, the 3D building is appearing, but the only problem is the building is too big and isn't located at the same place. I have tried many ways to include changing the projection, but it seems doesnt not solve the problem.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

because the value of Coordinate system origin is too large. so The center of the model coordinates should be small,You can put the (x,y) minus a value .